# MIN/MAX of array elements vertically across rows

Tags: arrays, postgresql, timescaledb

I am building a continuous aggregate in Timescaledb of a table containing values in an array.

```
db=> \d voltage_harmonics
                    Table "public.voltage_harmonics"
  Column  |            Type             | Collation | Nullable | Default
----------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 time     | timestamp without time zone |           | not null |
 meter_id | integer                     |           | not null |
 phase    | character varying(2)        |           | not null |
 value    | double precision[]          |           | not null |
Indexes:
    "voltage_harmonics_time_idx" btree ("time" DESC)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "voltage_harmonics_meter_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (meter_id) REFERENCES meters(id)
Triggers:
    ts_insert_blocker BEFORE INSERT ON voltage_harmonics FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION timescaledb_internal.insert_blocker()
```

The column `value` is of fixed cardinality of 127.

Example data looks as follows:

```
db=> SELECT time, meter_id, phase, value[1], value[2], value[3] FROM voltage_harmonics WHERE meter_id=1 AND phase='TN' ORDER BY time LIMIT 4;
            time            | meter_id | phase |       value        |        value        |       value
----------------------------+----------+-------+--------------------+---------------------+--------------------
 2020-12-17 10:21:26.673998 |        1 | TN    | 233.50682067871094 | 0.16370028257369995 |  1.062761664390564
 2020-12-17 10:21:27.693663 |        1 | TN    |   233.524169921875 | 0.17024844884872437 | 1.0571166276931763
 2020-12-17 10:21:28.691197 |        1 | TN    | 233.50201416015625 |  0.1778242588043213 |  1.066114902496338
 2020-12-17 10:21:29.690272 |        1 | TN    |  233.4673309326172 |  0.2070794403553009 | 1.0743005275726318
(4 rows)
```

What I would like is for my aggregate view to have columns `min` and `max` of type array of length 127 containing the min/max values across the different rows of the table. Something similar to the following query, only ideally containing all 127 elements of value:

```
db=> SELECT time_bucket('1 hour', time) AS hour, meter_id, phase, ARRAY[MIN(value[1]), MIN(value[2]), MIN(value[3]), MIN(value[4])] AS min, ARRAY[MAX(value[1]), MAX(value[2]), MAX(value[3])] AS max FROM voltage_harmonics WHERE meter_id=1 AND phase='RN' GROUP BY hour, meter_id, phase ORDER BY hour ASC limit 2;
        hour         | meter_id | phase |                                       min                                        |                             max
---------------------+----------+-------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------
 2020-12-17 10:00:00 |        1 | RN    | {232.52615356445312,0.011430807411670685,0.367933064699173,0.367933064699173}    | {234.22560119628906,0.47944650053977966,0.7849964499473572}
 2020-12-17 11:00:00 |        1 | RN    | {233.45909118652344,0.00765242101624608,0.43139347434043884,0.43139347434043884} | {234.91810607910156,0.5121793150901794,0.8960586190223694}
(2 rows)
```

A plain min/max of `value` does not seem to do the trick:

```
=> SELECT time_bucket('1 hour', time) AS hour, meter_id, phase, MIN(value[1:4]), MAX(value[1:4]) FROM voltage_harmonics WHERE meter_id=1 AND phase='RN' GROUP BY hour, meter_id, phase ORDER BY hour ASC limit 2;
        hour         | meter_id | phase |                                        min                                         |                                       max
---------------------+----------+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 2020-12-17 10:00:00 |        1 | RN    | {232.52615356445312,0.049829818308353424,0.41124674677848816,0.056136056780815125} | {234.22560119628906,0.09132575988769531,0.6057599186897278,0.05052584037184715}
 2020-12-17 11:00:00 |        1 | RN    | {233.45909118652344,0.23476898670196533,0.6725903749465942,0.12308577448129654}    | {234.91810607910156,0.20045030117034912,0.57932049036026,0.05590963736176491}
(2 rows)
```

So I'm wondering if there is a way to do MIN/MAX (or other aggregate functions) **vertically across table entries**, so the first entry of the MIN result has the minimum value of the first entries of all grouped rows, the second entry has the minimum value of the second entry of all grouped rows and so on. I realize I can achieve this by extending my query above to spell out all the 127 members of `value`, but I wonder if there is a better way.

Answer (score 2):

[step-by-step demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=7b5139f05e11f32861731ef14fda381c)

```
SELECT 
    ARRAY_AGG(min ORDER BY position),
    ARRAY_AGG(max ORDER BY position)
FROM (
    SELECT
        position,
        MIN(element),
        MAX(element)
    FROM t,
        unnest(val) WITH ORDINALITY as s(element, position)
    GROUP BY position
) s
```

1. Expand all array elements into one row each. Add the `WITH ORDINALITY` to store the position of each element in the array.
2. Group by `position` and find the related `MIN` and `MAX` values per array position
3. Reaggregate the `MIN` and `MAX` values into an array. The ordinality can be used to keep the original order.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to do the trick in plain PostgreSQL. However, when I try to create a timescaledb continuous aggregation using this query I get `ERROR:  aggregates with FILTER / DISTINCT / ORDER BY are not supported for continuous aggregate query`.

Comment: Try this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=fa4be3643c0bd09c5e519d050b875971 ORDER BY in the subquery, not in the array_agg

Comment: That seems to work for a regular view, though it seems somewhat fragile to the order of other (additional) columns included in the inner (and outer) select. I.e. they must be ordered in the inner query even if I do a group by those columns in the outer, ordering them in the outer query seems to mean that `ARRAY_AGG` aggregates the min/max out of order. But in any case, timescaledb gives me the error `ERROR:  aggregates which are not parallelizable are not supported by continuous aggregate query`. Perhaps this is simply not possible with timescaledb.

Comment: After trying to create a continuous aggregate (view) for the inner query only I stumbled upon https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb/issues/1717 which seems to indicate that this is currently not supported by timescaledb.